# Adding Load Balancer Rule via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-load-balancer

I'm attempting to add a load balancer rule via Powershell as we need to open multiple ports for passive ftp.

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId "MySubId"

$slb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name "MyLB" -ResourceGroupName "MyRG"

$prb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancerProbeConfig -Name "MyProbe" -LoadBalancer $slb

$beaddpool = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name "BEADDPOOL" -LoadBalancer $slb

$slb | Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name "PassivePort_50010" -FrontendIPConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] -BackendAddressPool $beaddpool -Protocol "Tcp" -FrontendPort 50010 -BackendPort 50010 -Probe $prb -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4

$slb | Set-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name "PassivePort_50010" -FrontendIPConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] -BackendAddressPool $beaddpool -Protocol "Tcp" -FrontendPort 50010 -BackendPort 50010 -Probe $prb -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4
```

As you can see above, I'm logging in, grabbing the LB in question, the LB Probe and the LB BackEndAddressPool. I'm then using Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig and Set-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermloadbalancerruleconfig?view=azurermps-6.8.1)

I can see from the PowerShell output that the rule is there. However it lacks one obvious property in comparison to those added via the portal.

**"ProvisioningState": "Succeeded"**

The new rule is not shown in the portal, but is visible when getting the LB via PS.

**Is there a way I'm missing to ensure the rule is displayed in the azure portal? Or does the rule take much longer to be provisioned in this way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've created properties you need to apply them:

```
$slb | Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer
```

Comment: Perfect, added it in to the PS with a for loop and the whole process becomes painless.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId "MySubId"

$slb = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name "MyLB" -ResourceGroupName "MyRG"

$slb | Add-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name "PassivePort_50010" -FrontendIPConfiguration $slb.FrontendIpConfigurations[0] -BackendAddressPool $beaddpool -Protocol "Tcp" -FrontendPort 50010 -BackendPort 50010 -Probe $prb -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4

$slb | Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer
```

For more details, you may refer similar [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/06fa15df-dc85-4c7b-8cbb-080eb2993d82/inbound-nat-rule-portal-support-for-load-balancers-associated-to-virtual-machine-scale-sets?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) thread, which addressing same issue.

Comment: you reading his question or not? has nothing do with nat rules.

Comment: Even for NATRuleConfig or RuleConfig it applies, any how I have updated the answer. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: it was misleading, not its just a dupe